# jQuery applying :nth-child(#) and addClass() to div, will not add class to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have tried many variations of applying the `:nth-child`, using 1, 2, 3, etc. trying to get a hit on the div I need to add a class to: `<div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">`.

I was able to add a class to the parent div: `.g-recaptcha` so I know my jQuery is working. I have also tried variations of `$('.g-recaptcha :nth-child(1)').addClass('bbbb');`, adding `div.g-recaptcha div:nth-child(1)` - prefixing with a div but still not luck.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or why I cannot get a class added to: `<div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">` ?

jQuery

```
$('.g-recaptcha :nth-child(1)').addClass('bbbb');
```

HTML

```
<div class="ginput_container">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le59BwTAAAAABBcVxJyYHAbAzfFn8D6cLyVdPm9" data-theme="light">
        <div>
            <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6Le59BwTAAAAABBcVxJyYHAbAzfFn8D6cLyVdPm9&amp;co=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zaWxraW5tYW5hZ2VtZW50Z3JvdXAuY29tOjgw&amp;hl=en&amp;v=r20160404124926&amp;theme=light&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=xksc4agtgw8z" title="recaptcha widget" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="undefined"></iframe>

            </div>

            <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea>

        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Reddy, that helps, but .ginput_container is on the page nearly 50 times, I think this is why I was trying to target the other class. Is this possible based on what I am trying to do?

Comment: are you sure that your div will have the same height and width as in the OP? or can it change ??

Comment: Is expected result for each `.g-recaptcha` element to have `className` set to `"bbbb"`? Or `.g-recaptcha` sibling element `className` set to `"bbbb"` ?

Comment: Hello @guest271314, no. It simply needs to be added to one instance as noted above. The other problem is there are multiple iframes. I really thought this suggestion ( $('div[style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"]').addClass('bbbb'); ) by Vincent G would solve it (it works in jfiddle, but not on my page), but for some reason, this will not add the class. I'm lost a bit now... Trying things.

Comment: Are there multiple `div` elements having attribute `style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"` ? Is requirement is to add `"bbbb"` to only first matched selector `div` having `style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"` attribute ?

Comment: No, just that one. I have some suspicion that this size dimension is being triggered out of sequence with the jQuery to catch it and it's not syncing up for some reason - total guess at this point, but can't figure out why I can write to other divs and not this one. Continuing to try things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

1) **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqvt9svj/)**

```
$('.g-recaptcha iframe').parent().addClass('bbbb');
```

get hold of the iframe inside the div `.g-recaptcha` and it is to this iframe parent div you need to add the class. So find the parent of this iframe and add the class.

This works if you have only 1 iframe inside your `.g-recaptcha` div, If your HTML structure doesnt support this code let me know... We can improve

2) **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqvt9svj/1/)**

```
  $('.g-recaptcha div:eq(1)').addClass('bbbb');
```

Use **[eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector to access the div's by index

3) **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqvt9svj/2/)**

```
$('.g-recaptcha div div').addClass('bbbb');
```

Since you have 2 nested div's you can find the inner div like this..

Also many more...

---

**Edit 1:** As suggested by  CupawnTae you can also do this

```
$('.g-recaptcha iframe[title="recaptcha widget"]').parent().addClass('bbbb');
```

Comment: nice idea. `$('[title="recaptcha widget"]').parent()` might work well too

Comment: Could this be a problem because the div is being generated after the jQuery? It's a reCaptcha script from Google. It just doesn't make sense that it's not writing to this specific div. I can write to other divs just fine.

Comment: @OldWest that can be the only reason, make sure you run the script after the div is generated.

Comment: Okee. I should be able to write this to the footer (not header) of the page. Going to try that, see what I get. Will let you know.

Comment: I tried that as well, no luck. And ensuring the script is in the footer changes nothing. Wow, makes me wonder if there is some type of block on that div.

Comment: @OldWest place a debugger in the script and check if that element is available , see what do you get `$('.g-recaptcha div div')` with this when u hit the debugger.

Comment: Reddy, I am sorry, but I am not certain how to place a debugger in it.

Comment: @OldWest add this line `debugger;` above the point where you want to start the debug from. Then open the browser developer window (press F12 to open it), Now reload the page and the debugger will hit this point where you placed, then just open the console tab (you will find it among those tabs in developer window), paste this code `$('.g-recaptcha div div')` and see what you get,

Comment: Hi @Reddy, thanks for the assistance. I am on a Mac using Chrome, F12 doesn't seem to do much. I can open source and Console, but doesn't seem to align with your suggestions - assume you are in different browser.

Comment: @OldWest I use Chrome too, if F12 doesnt work then you can right click anywhere on the page and then choose inspect element, this will open the developer window and opens the elements tab, but then you can move to other tabs

Comment: Sorry, I think this might be correct, this was returned: []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108722/discussion-between-reddy-and-oldwest).

Answer (score 2):

[With this way](https://jsfiddle.net/v3bLoofy/1/), you are sure to target the right `div` with your code :

```
$('div[style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"]').addClass('bbbb');
```

[OR this way :](https://jsfiddle.net/v3bLoofy/2/)

```
$('.g-recaptcha div').find('div').addClass('bbbb');
```

Comment: `$('.g-recaptcha div')` this will return nothing.. your second option is not valid here, have a check

Comment: I tested it, it works in both JSFiddle I've provided

Comment: @VincentG that was my mistake, I misinterpreted the HTML.

Comment: Although I like this, $('div[style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"]').addClass('bbbb'); it does not work for whatever reason.

Comment: Scratch what I said, sorry, I can see it's working on jFiddle, but it won't bite on my page... Hmmm.

Comment: Are you sure you use the same attributes on the div style on your page ?

Answer (score 0):

To target the first `div` inside a `div` inside `.g-recaptcha` you can use

```
.g-recaptcha>div>div:first-child
```

Or to target the parent of the element with `title="recaptcha widget"`, use

```
$('[title="recaptcha widget"]').parent()
```

Example:

```js
$('[title="recaptcha widget"]').parent().addClass('bbbb');
```

```css
.bbbb {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ginput_container">

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le59BwTAAAAABBcVxJyYHAbAzfFn8D6cLyVdPm9" data-theme="light"><div>

<div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6Le59BwTAAAAABBcVxJyYHAbAzfFn8D6cLyVdPm9&amp;co=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zaWxraW5tYW5hZ2VtZW50Z3JvdXAuY29tOjgw&amp;hl=en&amp;v=r20160404124926&amp;theme=light&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=xksc4agtgw8z" title="recaptcha widget" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="undefined"></iframe>

</div>

<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The div you are targeting is a sibling and not a child of `g-recaptcha`

Use something like

```
$('.g-recaptcha + div').addClass('bbbb');
```

Or use some selector like siblings()

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Problem is .g-recaptcha shows up many times on the page, I did not realize that until a few mins ago. Trying more things.